# 'template or render function not defined' error

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I've been stuck on this problem for days. I've tried everything I can find but still can't get it worked.

In `app.js` When I set like below, it works:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h('div', 'Hello World')
})
```

My codes:

`app.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import User from './App.vue'
import path from 'path'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(User)
})
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data: () => {
            message: 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue Webpack Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE[1]:

[HERE](https://github.com/wtflove/vue-webpack_demo) is my code

Also I did:

- `console.log(User)`, the output is ok.
- use template option in render function, and it works:

  `render: h => h({
    template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
  })`

I am so confused, seems for some reason I can't render a template from `.vue` file

Whole error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <App> at src/App.vue
   <Root>
warn @ vue.esm.js:611`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mount App.vue

Here is what I've changed:

in `App.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

in `main.js`

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(User)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in `export default {...}`, the fixed version:

```
export default {
    data: () => ({
        message: 'Hello World'
    })
}
```

Comment: That was the only issue I've noticed. You could also try remove `import path from 'path'` string. If it won't help please provide additional info about error you get.

Comment: That is the only error info I get... If you could see my code please see UPDATE[1]